# Trying to sort a pandas dataframe by a number column, but getting strange output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (called df) with a length of 460 that looks like this

```
index   Position   T/F
0       1          True
1       2          False
4       3          False
8       4          False
9       18         True
13      5          False
```

And I would like to sort it by 'position' so that the whole dataframe looks like this

```
index   Position   T/F
0       1          True
1       2          False
4       3          False
8       4          False
13      5          False
20      6          False
28      7          True
```

I have attempted to use

```
df = df.sort_values('Position', ascending=True)
```

However, that outputs a rather bizarre dataframe with this form

```
index   Position   T/F
0       1          True
52      10         False
456     100        False
470     101        False
477     102        False
...
59      11         False
666     110        False
644     111        True
...
1       2          False
```

You get the idea. I'm not sure why it's sorting it like this, but I would like to figure out how to fix this issue so that I can output the desired DataFrame

Comment: `Position` seems to be string. Use `df['position'] = df['position'].astype(int)` and then sort.

Comment: Your `Position` column is of `str` type. Try `df.Position = pd.to_numeric(df.Position)` and then sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Position` seems to be string.

```
df['position'] = df['position'].astype(int)
```

Then do sorting.

```
df = df.sort_values('Position', ascending=True)
```

Output:

```
index   Position   T/F
0       1          True
1       2          False
4       3          False
8       4          False
13      5          False
20      6          False
28      7          True
```